# RaggedTensor on TPU

Tags: python, tensorflow, tpu, ragged-tensors

I am trying to train a neural network using TensorFlow that takes as input (`tf.keras.layers.Input`) a [RaggedTensor](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/ragged_tensor). It works fine on CPU and GPU but I am really strugling to make it work on TPU. I wanted to know if some of you managed to make it work (not necessarily looking for a direct solution though it'd be great, some tooltips would already be great!). So far the error messages were explicit enough for me to go on, but I now struggle on how to go a bit further.

What I did so far:

1. I am using `tf.data.Dataset` to read data from TF_Records but I needed to explicitly transform it into a [DistributedDataset](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/distribute/DistributedDataset) to disable prefecthing.

```py
strategy.experimental_distribute_dataset(
    dataset,
    tf.distribute.InputOptions(
        experimental_prefetch_to_device=False
    )
)
```

2. I got `Compilation failure: Detected unsupported operations when trying to compile graph ... on XLA_TPU_JIT: RaggedTensorToTensor` which could be (sort-of) fixed by allowing soft device placement:

```py
tf.config.set_soft_device_placement(True)
```

3. I now get stuck with `Compilation failure: Input 1 to node '.../RaggedReduceSum/RaggedReduce/RaggedSplitsToSegmentIds/Repeat/SequenceMask/Range' with op Range must be a compile-time constant.`. I totally understand why I have this error, I am fully aware of [available ops on TPU](https://cloud.google.com/tpu/docs/tensorflow-ops) and in particular that most of the dynamic operations should be determined at compile-time to run on TPU. But I can't think how I could use those ragged-tensors with TPU then...

Any idea would be appreciated :)

*P.S.: I haven't seen much news from the TensorFlow team on RaggedTensors on TPU since [this answer](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/27170#issuecomment-655777241) back in July 2020, but I may have missed a bunch about it... Pointing to the git threads would already be great for me if I can investigate more.*

Comment: P.P.S: I also know I could use a masking system to use static-size Tensors instead of Ragged ones... But if I can avoid this, that would be great :-)

Comment: Seems like they don't have the support yet.